# Node.js の Web アプリケーションでデータストアに NoSQL の採用例が多い理由は？

Tags: node.js

様々なプログラミング言語や Web フレームワークで REST API サーバを開発するチュートリアルを眺めていたところ、Java, Python, Ruby, PHP などでは RDB を使っていたのですが、Node.js では NoSQL（特に MongoDB）の採用が非常に多いことが気になりました。

なぜ Node.js では RDB は採用されにくいのでしょうか？
これは、Web フロントエンドで採用される言語が TypeScript 一強の時代であるにも関わらず、Node.js で動いている有名サービスが少ないことと関係あるでしょうか。

Comment: 「非常に多い」のは「チュートリアル」の話ですか？それとも実用的な製品(OSSを含む)、または、運用されているサービスでの話ですか？いずれにしても、「非常に多い」と主張する客観的に検証可能な根拠はありますか？

Comment: はい「チュートリアル」の話です。

>「非常に多い」と主張する客観的に検証可能な根拠はありますか？
こちらについてはありません。あくまで個人の感想です。